# Character Encoding and the â€™ Issue

Tags: character-encoding, cross-platform, mojibake

Even today, one frequently sees character encoding problems with significant frequency.  Take for example this recent job post:

[image: Bad Encoding]

*(**Note**: This is an example, not a spam job post... :-)*

I have recently seen that exact error on websites, in popular IM programs, and in the background graphics on CNN.

My two-part question:

- What causes this particular, common encoding issue?
- As a developer, what should I do with user input to avoid common encoding issues like
  this one?  If this question requires simplification to provide a
  meaningful answer, assume content is entered through a web browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *What causes this particular, common encoding issue?*

This will occur when the conversion between characters and bytes has taken place using the wrong charset. Computers handles data as bytes, but to represent the data in a sensible manner to humans, it has to be converted to characters (strings). This conversion takes place based on a charset of which there are many different ones.

In the particular `â€™` example, this is a typical CP1252 representation of the [Unicode Character 'RIGHT SINQLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) `’` which was been read using UTF-8. In UTF-8, that character exist of the bytes `0xE2`, `0x80` and `0x99`. If you check the [CP1252 codepage layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout), then you'll see that those bytes represent exactly the characters `â`, `€` and `™`.

This can be caused by the website not having read in the original source properly (it should have used CP1252 for this), or is displaying an UTF-8 page with the wrong  `charset=CP1252` attribute in `Content-Type` response header (or the attribute is missing; on Windows machines the default charset of CP1252 would be used then).

---

> *As a developer, what should I do with user input to avoid common encoding issues like this one? If this question requires simplification to provide a meaningful answer, assume content is entered through a web browser.*

Ensure that you read the characters from arbitrary byte stream sources (e.g. a file, an URL, a network socket, etc) using a known and predefinied charset. Then, ensure that you're consistently storing, writing and sending it using an Unicode charset, preferably UTF-8.

If you're familiar with Java (your question history confirms this), you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) useful.