# Displaying some sort of apostrophe (Currently shows as diamond)

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

Some rows in my database contain an apostrophe of sorts, that, when displayed with PHP, are converted to diamonds with a question mark in the center. Example, if it copies correctly: `Captain Jim O’Brien`

These "apostrophes"  were inserted most likely via TinyMCE, where the user was copying and pasting from Word, or something from a Mac computer perhaps.

How can I display these "apostrophes"? When I view the row in PHPMyAdmin, the apostrophes are displayed (no diamond), so there is obviously a way.

My character encoding is set to UTF-8, and I've tried `htmlspecialchars($string)` and `htmlentities($string)`, with no luck.

Comment: Did you try `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`? With character encoding, you should always specify what encoding (UTF8, etc.) you're using - if you didn't already.

Comment: @newfurniturey That actually displays a blank name when the name contains the invalid apostrophe.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you:  http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet

Comment: @newfurniturey It's appearing blank because it's actually throwing a `Invalid multibyte sequence` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters are encoded in different places.

MySQL has a particular character encoding.  By default, it is *not* UTF-8 but rather latin1.

The HTML document you generate using PHP also has a particular character encoding specified.  Finally, the actual bytes in the HTML document factually assume a particular character encoding, which if you're not careful can be different than the character encoding you specify for the document.

Verify that your MySQL encoding is set to UTF-8 as a first step.  Note that MySQL can have the default character encoding for the database overridden on a per-table or even per-column basis.

You may be interested in this related post to get a deeper understanding of character encoding

[Character Encoding and the â€™ Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8421316/141172)

**Update**

Something put the data into the MySQL database in the first place.  Perhaps that "something" was not using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: MySQL Collation for the table: `utf8_general_ci`. The HTML document has set `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Collation is different than character encoding.  Check the encoding (though if collation is utf8 based, the encoding is *probably* utf8)

Comment: Also... what's the encoding that you see in PHPMyAdmin when you view source on a page that shows the apostrophe correctly?  Is it UTF8 or something else?

Comment: Using `show variables like "character_set_database";`, I get latin1. So, I realize that I probably need to change the encoding of the database to UTF-8. That being said, somehow PHPMyAdmin is displaying it without changing the database. The source code shows that they are setting the `Content-Type` to UTF8

Comment: PHPMyAdmin appears to be displaying the apostrophe as `&rsquo;`, but I'm not sure how they converted it to that?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin may be using a latin1 compatible encoding that happens to match the encoding in MySQL.

Comment: Changing my `Content-Type` meta tag to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">` fixes the issue for that page. I'll keep trying other solutions. If I change the encoding of my DB from latin1 to UTF8, what ramifications can that have to other data? And does that automatically fix the issue?

Comment: Changed the encoding of the table only to UTF-8, that does not automatically fix the issue. Unless something is overriding the table encoding.

Comment: You will probably need to re-load the data (and ensure that the original data is UTF-8 encoded).

Comment: The trick was to ensure that the page that housed the form (entry) was UTF-8, database was UTF-8, and the output page was UTF-8. This doesn't solve the problem characters already in the database, but it prevents new ones from being entered. Thanks!