# Character encoding issue with SMS messaging

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have built an SMS application that allows users to send from a webpage. The application works great, but I have found an issue that occurs when text is pasted in from another source such as gmail.

Take the following examples:

**When typed in manually**
*INPUT:* `There's a problem`
*OUTPUT:* `There's a problem`

**When pasted in from gmail**
*INPUT:* `There’s a problem`
*OUTPUT:* `There?s a problem`

I believe that this is caused by the UNICODE `’` not being available in ASCII/UTF-8, but I cannot seem to convert it successfully. Does anyone have recommendations for fixing this with PHP or JS?

I have tried `mb_convert_encoding` and `iconv` with no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying some sort of apostrophe (Currently shows as diamond)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634892/displaying-some-sort-of-apostrophe-currently-shows-as-diamond)

Comment: @Script47 This doesn't involve a database

Comment: BTW, that apostrophe looks somewhat weird on my screen, like some sort of "smart quotes" type of apostrophe.