# How can I find out which character a certain string is encoding in my database?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

Recently I exported parts of my `mySQL` database, and noticed that the text had several strange characters in it. For example, the string `â€™` often appeared.

When trying to find out what this meant, I found the stackoverflow question: [Character Encoding and the â€™ Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421316/character-encoding-and-the-%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-issue). From that question I now know that the string `â€™` stands for a quote.

But how can I find out more generally what a string of characters stands for? For example, the letter `Â` often appears in my database as well, and is actually causing me a problem now on a certain page, and to solve the problem, I would like to know what that character means.

I've looked at several tables showing character encoding, but haven't been able to figure out how to use these tables to see why `â€™` means `'`, or, more importantly for me, what `Â` stands for. I'd be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: UTF8 is huge, usually https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html helps with the most common characters. And next time first check the encoding before exporting

Comment: @nbk Thanks very much! I found `Â` in the table and it turned out it stood for `U+00A0`, which is a non-breaking space – this will help me solve my other problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latin1 encoding for `â€™` is (in hex) `E28099`.

The utf8 encoding for `’` is `E28099`.

But you pasted in `C3A2E282ACE284A2`, which is the "double encoding" of that apostrophe.

What apparently happened is that you had `’` in the client; the client was generating utf8 encodings.  But your connection parameters to MySQL said "latin1".  So, your `INSERT` statement dutifully treated it as 3 latin1 characters `E2 80 99` (visually `â€™`), and converted each one to utf8, hex `C3A2 E282AC E284A2`.

Read about "double encoding" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Meanwhile, browsers tend to be forgiving about double-encoding, or else it might have shown `Ã¢â‚¬â„¢`

latin1 characters are each 1 byte (2 hex digits).  utf8/utf8mb4 characters are 1-to-4 bytes; some 2-byte and 3-byte encodings showed up in your exercise.

As for `Â`...  Go to http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#8_bit_encodings and look at the second table there.  Notice how the first two columns have lots of things starting with `Â`.  In latin1, that is hex `C2`.  In utf8, many punctuation marks are encoded as 2 bytes: `C2xx`.  For example, the copyright symbol, `©` is utf8 hex `C2A9`, which is misinterpreted `Â©`.